# react-router 1.0.0-rc3 - All URLs are are mapped to only one React component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following routes:
**routes.jsx**

```
var routes = (
    <Route component={AfApp} path="/">
        <Route path="/testpage" component={Test}/>
        <Route path="testpage" component={Test}/>
    </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

But when I navigated to `mydomain/testpage`, `mydomain/testpage/` and `mydomain/whatever`, only the **AfApp** component rendered, not the **TestPage** component or any other component!

What is wrong?
**AfApp.jsx**

```
export default class AfApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log('render');

        return (

            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );

    }
}
```

**entry.jsx**

```
import routes from './routes.jsx';
ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes} />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

React version is 0.14.0

The bundle.js that is included in my page contains the following:

```
var _appComponentsTestJsx2 = _interopRequireDefault(_appComponentsTestJsx);

var routes = _react2['default'].createElement(
    _reactRouter.Route,
    { component: _appComponentsAfAppJsx2['default'], path: '/' },
    _react2['default'].createElement(_reactRouter.Route, { path: '/testpage', component: _appComponentsTestJsx2['default'] }),
    _react2['default'].createElement(_reactRouter.Route, { path: 'testpage', component: _appComponentsTestJsx2['default'] })
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I don't understand adding the history (of course I had to run `npm install history`) made the problem go away:
**entry.jsx**

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
ReactDOM.render(<Router history={createBrowserHistory()} routes={routes} />, document.getElementById('content'));
```